# Cool Modular Arithmetics.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a$ be the remainder when $1124^{2017}$ is divided by $2017$.

Find the value of $a^{2048}$ $(\text{mod } 45)$

Comment: Any thoughts?  The fact that $2017$ is a prime might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. (These are routine elementary number theory problems, cool only for beginners.)

Comment: Wait, are you not allowed to ask questions for people just to solve for fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2017$ is prime so by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) you can know *exactly* what $a \equiv 1124^{2017}\mod 2017$ is with no calculation.

Then find $\gcd(a, 45)$ and it's easy to see it is $1$ so $a$ and $45$ are relatively prime ($45$ has only $5$ and $3$ as prime factors; $a$ will not have either of those).  [$\phi(45)= \phi(5)\phi(3^2) = 4*(3-1)*3 = 24$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Then you have $a^{2048}=a^{85*24+8}$ and you can use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to solve $a^{85*24+8}\mod 45$.

[Final Hint: $1124 = 24*45 + 44$]